removal usb rule for polkit
I'm having trouble writing a rule that would allow all (or some subset of users) to access a yubikey (a usb security device). The device appears as /dev/hidraw2, and the normal user is on an ACL (access control list) that grants permission to use it. However, if a second user is also logged in, they're not on the device's ACL. The system is running openrc and not systemd, so elogind is control the ACLs. (elogind is a daemon for openrc that emulated some of the systemd functionality that openrc doesn't have out of the box).
When I manually add a secondary user to the ACL for this device with setfacl, this works. But, it's not persistent, and when the device is removed and re-inserted, setfacl has to be called again.
As far as I can tell, elogind uses polkit to determine which user gets put on an ACL. But, I've not been able to write a polkit rule that would allow all users (or some limited subset of all users) to use the device. Here's an example of a rule that I tried:
    if ( subject.isInGroup("plugdev")) {
            return polkit.Result.YES;
        }
    }
});

That example is far to permissive, since it should allow anyone in plugdev to access any device (I think). But even that doesn't allow secondary users to access the device. I've looked at a ton of polkit example rules, and I'm kind of stumped. Any ideas?
